# problems with plotting very big 2d graph

Tags: c++, graph, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

its needed to plot a 2d graph consisting of `10^3` (practically can reach up to `5*10^6`) points which are given in a file with a very high precision

sample points:

```
          x               y = f(x)
-----------------------------------------
0.0000000000000e+000 9.9453146383711e+006
1.0107375000000e-002 1.0053545400632e+007
2.0211374000000e-002 9.9475746573179e+006
3.0315250000000e-002 1.0051184341654e+007
4.0418752000000e-002 9.9500284997072e+006
5.0525375000000e-002 1.0048588691478e+007
6.0629874000000e-002 9.9527328766918e+006
7.0733748000000e-002 1.0045819834233e+007
8.0837503000000e-002 9.9556071710602e+006
...
```

As it can be noticed `x, and f(x)` are in a very non-comfortable range to plot, thus,

I wrote a function to convert them from one range `[a, b]` to another `[c, d]` in order to plot a whole graph in a rectangular area with certain dimensions (`w=780` and `h=550`)

```
// mapping x from [a, b] to [c, d]
qreal Graph::mapTo(qreal x, qreal a, qreal b, qreal c, qreal d)
{
    qreal denom = b - a;

    if (denom != 0.0f)
    {
        return (x - a)*(d - c)/denom + c;
    }

    return 0.0f;
}
//...
qreal x1 = mapTo(points[i].x(), 0, maxX, 0, w);
qreal y1 = mapTo(points[i].y(), minY, maxY, 0, h);

qreal x2 = mapTo(points[i+1].x(), 0, maxX, 0, w);
qreal y2 = mapTo(points[i+1].y(), minY, maxY, 0, h);
```

But after this conversion huge accuracy was lost...and I got this kind of values which resulted in a straight horizontal line (instead of a curve) after plotting..

```
x = 0         y = 549.453
x = 0.762673  y = 549.447
x = 1.52509   y = 549.453
x = 2.2875    y = 549.447
x = 3.04988   y = 549.453
x = 3.8125    y = 549.447
x = 4.57496   y = 549.453
x = 5.33736   y = 549.447
x = 6.09976   y = 549.452
```

I know that some real numbers can't be represented with `floating point` arithmetics in computers but in this case it seems like `y` values lost too much accuracy isn't it ??

What Am I doing wrong that causes those values ?

What algorithms should I use to save accuracy between mathematical operations in this case ?

Comment: What is `qreal`?  Also `denom != 0.0f` -- if the denominator is close to 0, you still have an issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `qreal` is from `Qt` which is a typedef for `double`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie which issue your talking about ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark hmm, number of points practically can reach `5*10^6` but in this case there are only `10^3` points

Comment: @ampawd -- You are comparing if the denominator is not exactly 0.  Comparing floating point for (in)exactness to a specific number shouldn't be done.  What if the denominator is `0.00000000000002`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie do you mean its better comparing like ` fabs(denom) < epsilon` ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but why its not shouldn't be done, if it is not exact zero then we can divide ? where is this is rule breaking ?

Comment: @ampawd -- You should be testing if the denominator is "far enough" from 0, both positive and negative side, for your requirements.  What if `b - a` was *supposed* to yield 0, but instead, a very tiny number?  That throws off your routine into doing a division it wasn't supposed to do.  Not only do you risk having erroneous results, you risk having your function work differently with a change of compilers, compiler options, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just tried comparing with an EPS = 1e-5 and got same results

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark cant you suggest any ideas ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark from what are this problem is ? And what algorithms do I have to look into to get more knowledge for solving it ? The data I have to plot is stored in a file where as `(x, y)` where x is a horizontal axis mark, and y is value in a vertical axis. `x` are sorted in increasing order,`y` are not, difference between next and current `y` value is very small for all data, and diff for `x` is constant

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the graph should be plotted as "points connected with lines"

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark   I did find why it was giving such inaccurate results for `y` values - Its needed to find `minY` and `maxY` for `y` s to correctly map them to the range `[0, h]` - after fixing this graph became looking more like a 2D graph of some function. Now there's another problem: if number of points is high (even for 1 million with tail) rendering gets very slow...so I might use `OpenGL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least found why it was giving such innacurate results for `y` values

Its needed to find `minY` and `maxY` for `y` s to correctly map them to the range `[0, h]` - after fixing this graph became looking more like a 2D graph of some function.

Now there's another problem: if number of points is high (1 million) rendering gets very slow...